# Jmeter Test do not end

Tags: jmeter

I have an issue with Jmeter that when the test is running it hangs after completion of few users Ex: Out of 20 users, sometimes it executes for 8 to 10 users and hangs. It does not end test. The test is having 8 thread groups but I am running only one thread group at a time. Since initially executing the test for less number of users I have run the test in GUI mode and NonGUI mode but still, I am having the same results.

**System configuration:**

```
1. Java version : 1.8.0_91
2. OS: Windows Server 2008 R2, 64-bit server
3. RAM : 7GB
4. JMeter version: 3.0
5. Set Environment variables for Java and Jmeter
6. Heap memory:   set HEAP=-Xms1024m -Xmx5120m
                        set NEW=-XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=1536m
                        set SURVIVOR=-XX:SurvivorRatio=8-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=50%
                        set TENURING=-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=2
                        set PERM=-XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
7. Java Opts:   -Xms512m -Xmx5632m
```

Can anyone help me how to resolve this?

**Jmeter log:**

```
2016/07/14 09:58:45 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US
2016/07/14 09:58:46 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading user properties from: D:\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\user.properties
2016/07/14 09:58:46 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading system properties from: D:\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\system.properties
2016/07/14 09:58:46 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2016 The Apache Software Foundation
2016/07/14 09:58:46 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 3.0 r1743807
2016/07/14 09:58:46 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_91
2016/07/14 09:58:46 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
2016/07/14 09:58:46 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.name=Windows Server 2008 R2
2016/07/14 09:58:46 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.arch=amd64
2016/07/14 09:58:46 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.version=6.1
2016/07/14 09:58:46 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: file.encoding=Cp1252
2016/07/14 09:58:46 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Max memory     =1670381568
2016/07/14 09:58:46 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Available Processors =4
2016/07/14 09:58:46 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United States)
2016/07/14 09:58:46 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United States)
2016/07/14 09:58:46 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=D:\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0
2016/07/14 09:58:46 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =D:\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin
2016/07/14 09:58:46 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =D:\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin
2016/07/14 09:58:46 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: IP: 10.0.0.12 Name: Performance FullName: Performance.Performance6220.b6.internal.cloudapp.net
2016/07/14 09:58:47 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.LookAndFeelCommand: Using look and feel: javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel [Metal, CrossPlatform]
2016/07/14 09:58:47 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loaded icon properties from org/apache/jmeter/images/icon.properties
2016/07/14 09:58:49 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.'
2016/07/14 09:58:49 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.'
2016/07/14 09:58:51 INFO  - kg.apc.jmeter.JMeterPluginsUtils: JMeter-Plugins.org v.1.4.0
2016/07/14 09:58:52 INFO  - jmeter.util.BSFTestElement: Registering JMeter version of JavaScript engine as work-round for BSF-22
2016/07/14 09:58:53 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2016/07/14 09:58:53 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2016/07/14 09:58:53 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2016/07/14 09:58:53 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2016/07/14 09:58:53 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2016/07/14 09:58:53 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
2016/07/14 09:58:54 INFO  - jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'keytool'
2016/07/14 09:58:54 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file D:\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\proxyserver.jks
2016/07/14 09:58:54 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.config.MongoSourceElement
2016/07/14 09:58:54 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.sampler.MongoScriptSampler
2016/07/14 09:58:55 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.DistributionGraphVisualizer
2016/07/14 09:58:55 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2016/07/14 09:58:55 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
2016/07/14 09:58:55 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2016/07/14 09:58:55 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
2016/07/14 09:58:55 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.SplineVisualizer
2016/07/14 09:59:05 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='D:\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin'
2016/07/14 09:59:05 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: D:\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\MED_PERF_DASHBOARDS_S5.jmx
2016/07/14 09:59:05 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='D:\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin'
2016/07/14 09:59:06 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2016/07/14 09:59:06 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2016/07/14 09:59:06 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 2.9
2016/07/14 09:59:06 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: All converter versions present and correct
2016/07/14 09:59:06 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Loading file: D:\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\MED_PERF_DASHBOARDS_S5.jmx
2016/07/14 09:59:06 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager: Settings: Delete null: true Check: true Allow variable: true Save: false Prefix: COOKIE_
2016/07/14 09:59:06 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CacheManager: Will only cache the following methods: [GET]
2016/07/14 09:59:10 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='D:\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin'
2016/07/14 10:00:59 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2016/07/14 10:00:59 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2016/07/14 10:00:59 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2016/07/14 10:00:59 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*)
2016/07/14 10:01:00 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : TRANSACTION TRENDS
2016/07/14 10:01:00 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 20 threads for group TRANSACTION TRENDS.
2016/07/14 10:01:00 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2016/07/14 10:01:00 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 20 ramp-up 50 perThread 2500.0 delayedStart=false
2016/07/14 10:01:00 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-1
2016/07/14 10:01:00 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Stored: C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\users1-150.csv
2016/07/14 10:01:00 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHCAbstractImpl: Local host = Performance
2016/07/14 10:01:00 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: HTTP request retry count = 0
2016/07/14 10:01:00 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2016/07/14 10:01:00 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2016/07/14 10:01:00 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.LazySchemeSocketFactory: Setting up HTTPS TrustAll Socket Factory
2016/07/14 10:01:00 INFO  - jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager: Using default SSL protocol: TLS
2016/07/14 10:01:00 INFO  - jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager: SSL session context: per-thread
2016/07/14 10:01:01 INFO  - jmeter.util.SSLManager: JmeterKeyStore Location:  type JKS
2016/07/14 10:01:01 INFO  - jmeter.util.SSLManager: KeyStore created OK
2016/07/14 10:01:01 WARN  - jmeter.util.SSLManager: Keystore file not found, loading empty keystore
2016/07/14 10:01:02 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-2
2016/07/14 10:01:05 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-3
2016/07/14 10:01:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-4
2016/07/14 10:01:10 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-5
2016/07/14 10:01:12 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-6
2016/07/14 10:01:15 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-7
2016/07/14 10:01:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-8
2016/07/14 10:01:20 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-9
2016/07/14 10:01:22 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-10
2016/07/14 10:01:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-11
2016/07/14 10:01:27 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-12
2016/07/14 10:01:30 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-13
2016/07/14 10:01:32 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-14
2016/07/14 10:01:35 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-15
2016/07/14 10:01:37 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-16
2016/07/14 10:01:40 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-17
2016/07/14 10:01:42 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-18
2016/07/14 10:01:45 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-19
2016/07/14 10:01:47 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-20
2016/07/14 10:04:49 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-5
2016/07/14 10:04:49 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-5
2016/07/14 10:04:52 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-3
2016/07/14 10:04:52 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-3
2016/07/14 10:04:53 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-4
2016/07/14 10:04:53 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-4
2016/07/14 10:04:53 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-2
2016/07/14 10:04:53 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-2
2016/07/14 10:04:55 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-6
2016/07/14 10:04:55 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-6
2016/07/14 10:04:56 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-7
2016/07/14 10:04:56 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-7
2016/07/14 10:05:02 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-1
2016/07/14 10:05:02 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-1
2016/07/14 10:06:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-19
2016/07/14 10:06:07 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-19
2016/07/14 10:06:10 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-20
2016/07/14 10:06:10 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-20
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Start: Stopping test
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-12
2016/07/14 10:21:25 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-12 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-18
2016/07/14 10:21:25 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-18 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-8
2016/07/14 10:21:25 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-8 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-15
2016/07/14 10:21:25 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-15 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-11
2016/07/14 10:21:25 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-11 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-13
2016/07/14 10:21:25 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-13 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-10
2016/07/14 10:21:25 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-10 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-16
2016/07/14 10:21:25 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-16 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-14
2016/07/14 10:21:25 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-14 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-9
2016/07/14 10:21:25 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-9 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-17
2016/07/14 10:21:25 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-17 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-11
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-12
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-13
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-18
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-10
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-8
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-9
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-16
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-17
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-15
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-14
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Close: C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\users1-150.csv
2016/07/14 10:21:25 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
2016/07/14 10:53:35 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2016/07/14 10:53:35 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2016/07/14 10:53:35 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*)
2016/07/14 10:53:36 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : TRANSACTION TRENDS
2016/07/14 10:53:36 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 20 threads for group TRANSACTION TRENDS.
2016/07/14 10:53:36 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2016/07/14 10:53:36 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 20 ramp-up 50 perThread 2500.0 delayedStart=false
2016/07/14 10:53:36 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-1
2016/07/14 10:53:36 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Stored: C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\users1-150.csv
2016/07/14 10:53:36 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2016/07/14 10:53:36 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2016/07/14 10:53:38 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-2
2016/07/14 10:53:41 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-3
2016/07/14 10:53:43 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-4
2016/07/14 10:53:46 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-5
2016/07/14 10:53:49 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-6
2016/07/14 10:53:51 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-7
2016/07/14 10:53:53 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-8
2016/07/14 10:53:56 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-9
2016/07/14 10:53:59 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-10
2016/07/14 10:54:01 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-11
2016/07/14 10:54:04 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-12
2016/07/14 10:54:06 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-13
2016/07/14 10:54:09 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-14
2016/07/14 10:54:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-15
2016/07/14 10:54:14 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-16
2016/07/14 10:54:16 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-17
2016/07/14 10:54:19 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-18
2016/07/14 10:54:21 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-19
2016/07/14 10:54:24 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-20
2016/07/14 10:58:05 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-2
2016/07/14 10:58:05 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-2
2016/07/14 10:58:06 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-5
2016/07/14 10:58:06 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-5
2016/07/14 10:58:08 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-4
2016/07/14 10:58:08 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-4
2016/07/14 10:58:09 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-7
2016/07/14 10:58:09 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-7
2016/07/14 10:58:13 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-6
2016/07/14 10:58:13 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-6
2016/07/14 10:58:35 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-1
2016/07/14 10:58:35 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-1
2016/07/14 10:58:45 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-18
2016/07/14 10:58:45 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-18
2016/07/14 10:58:51 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-20
2016/07/14 10:58:51 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-20
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Start: Stopping test
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-16
2016/07/14 11:51:17 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-16 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-10
2016/07/14 11:51:17 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-10 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-10
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-17
2016/07/14 11:51:17 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-17 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-16
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-8
2016/07/14 11:51:17 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-8 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-9
2016/07/14 11:51:17 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-9 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-8
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-14
2016/07/14 11:51:17 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-14 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-9
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-17
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-14
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-11
2016/07/14 11:51:17 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-11 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-13
2016/07/14 11:51:17 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-13 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-11
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-15
2016/07/14 11:51:17 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-15 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-19
2016/07/14 11:51:17 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-19 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-3
2016/07/14 11:51:17 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-3 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-15
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-13
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-19
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-12
2016/07/14 11:51:17 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-12 sampler: 433 /medevolveAnalytics/leftMenuSubmit
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-3
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TRANSACTION TRENDS 1-12
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Close: C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\users1-150.csv
2016/07/14 11:51:17 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

[image]
[image: Users and rampup]

[image: Users do not end]

Comment: System specs are good enough and there should not be any issue such sort of test even in GUI mode. From the log it appears that JMeter is creating threads successfully and also threads are stopped successfully. Have you tried this with disabled listeners? and some different test plan targeting different application/module!!

Answer (score 1):

The possible reasons are:

1. Incorrect behaviour of your application, i.e. it doesn't return any form of error when something goes wrong hence JMeter requests don't end. Consider setting reasonable Response Timeout on [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request).
2. Your application is overloaded and fails to respond. Consider monitoring its resources during the test via i.e. [PerfMon plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/), maybe it is just resource lack. See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)